# Non-trivial topological line bundles over cartesian product of manifolds not coming from a pullback

Tags: vector-bundles, at.algebraic-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be connected smooth manifolds. Let $L$ be a topological real line
bundle over $X\times Y$. Then we know that the isomorphism class of such a line bundle is determined by its first Stiefel-Whitney class $w_1(L)\in H^1(X\times Y,\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z})$.

I would like to have an example of a nontrivial line bundle $L$ (so $w_1(L)\neq 0$), such that

**(1)** $\forall y\in Y$ we have $w_1(L)|_{X\times\{y\}}=0\in H^1(X\times\{y\},\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z})$.

**(2)**  $L$ is not the pullback of a line bundle over $Y$.

I don't see how to construct such a line bundle. May be there is some trick using Kunneth's formula.

Comment: This holds trivially if $L$ is the pullback of a nontrivial line bundle on $Y$.  Do you want your condition to be true simultaneously for both $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that I don't want $L$ to be coming from the pullback of a line bundle over $Y$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Denote by $p_X$ the natural projection $X\times Y\to X$ and define $p_Y$ similarly.  Kunneth formula shows that any $\newcommand{\bZ}{\mathbb{Z}}$  $w\in H^1(X\times Y,\bZ/2)$ has the form

$$ w= p_X^* u+p_Y^* v,\;\;u\in H^1(X,\bZ/2),\;\;v\in H^1(Y,\bZ/2). $$

This proves that any  real line bundle  $L\to X\times Y$    has the form

$$ L= p_X^*L_X\otimes p_Y^*L_Y, $$

with

$$w_1(L)=p_X^*w_1(L_X)+p^*_Y w_1(L_Y). $$

Moreover

$$ L|_{X\times y}= L_X. $$

The line bundles with the properties you want are all pullbacks of nontrivial line bundles on $Y$.

Comment: I see, so this explains why I was not able to construct such an example. What about complex line bundle?

Comment: Ok, I was being idiot

Comment: Complex line bundles are classified by $H^2$ (with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$), so you can get extra line bundles on a product that come from $H^1(X)\otimes H^1(Y)$.  The simplest example of this is for $X=Y=S^1$: every complex line bundle on $X$ or $Y$ is trivial, but $H^2(X\times Y)=\mathbb{Z}$.